# HTML5 Video Seekable Play Progress Bar

Tags: video, custom-controls, progress-bar, html5-video, seekbar

I am trying to build a page with a html5 video and custom controls and I don't know how to do the seekable - play progress bar with a functionality that allows user dragging a head of it (pointer) and skipping parts of a video - getting to the point they want.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use the [jquery ui slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider).